# Randomness test of my own Python RNG

Tags: python, random, scipy

This a special assignment to me which I am not able to understand and I get confused.
I have the following Random Number Generator class.

#### rng.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class rngA():   
    def __init__(self, seed=0): self.state = seed
    def setSeed(self, seed): self.state = seed
    def rand(self): return 1.0*self.next()/(1<<32)
    def current(self): return self.state    
    def next(self):
        self.state = (69069 * self.state + 12345) & 0xFFFFFFFF
        return self.state

class rngB():   
    def __init__(self, seed=1): self.state = seed
    def setSeed(self, seed): self.state = seed
    def rand(self): return 1.0*self.next()/(1<<31)
    def current(self): return self.state    
    def next(self):
        self.state = (65539 * self.state + 4294967296) & 0x7FFFFFFF
        return self.state

class rngC():   
    def __init__(self, seed=1): self.state = seed
    def setSeed(self, seed): self.state = seed
    def rand(self): return 1.0*self.next()/(1<<12)
    def current(self): return self.state    
    def next(self):
        self.state = ((((16339 * self.state>>4 + 1) & 0xFF) + 4294967296) & 0x7FFFFFFF)<<4
        return self.state

class rngD():   
    def __init__(self, seed=1): 
        self.state = self.store = seed
    def setSeed(self, seed): self.state = seed
    def rand(self): return 1.0*self.next()/(1<<32)
    def current(self): return self.state    
    def next(self):
        self.store = self.state
        self.state = (69069 * self.state + 12345) & 0xFFFFFFFF
        self.state = int(.8*self.state+0.2*self.store)
        return self.state

class rngE():   
    def __init__(self, seed=12345): self.state = seed
    def setSeed(self, seed): self.state = seed
    def rand(self): return 1.0*self.next()/(1<<31)
    def current(self): return self.state    
    def next(self):
        self.state = (397204094 * self.state ) & 0x7FFFFFFF
        return self.state
```

How can I test the Randomness of the RNGs.

There is a some test out there like

```
1.Frequency test
2.Runs test
3.Autocorrelation test
4.Gap test
5.Poker test
```

But I am not able to understand how to do this with python. Please help me a way out that I can achieve my task.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please explain Randomness first?

Comment: Randomness meaning whether it generate Random Number or not, there is no repetition of number. like that @m170897017

Comment: @ShantanuBanerjee Isn't your question too broad?  I'd start with the
first part, Frequency Test, using my textbook and my class notes. If
I'm not too rusty, it's about binning a large number of outcomes and
computing some sample statistics to be compared with statistical
provisions about samples from a theoretically random distribution, but
this being an assignment shouldn't you know all this stuff better than
me? As soon as you have an idea of what to do, come back with a new,
specific question about coding and you'll find all the help you
need. Rinse, repeat for the other tests. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple sample like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def test_function():

    test_times = 10000

    a_object = rngA()
    b_object = rngB()
    c_object = rngC()
    d_object = rngD()

    a_res = []
    b_res = []
    c_res = []
    d_res = []

    for i in xrange(test_times):
        a_res.append(a_object.rand)
        b_res.append(b_object.rand)
        c_res.append(c_object.rand)
        d_res.append(d_object.rand)

    test_res = a_res + b_res + c_res + d_res

    if len(set(test_res)) != test_times*4:
        print 'test fails, there is recepition!!'
    else:
        print 'test passes, they are all random!!'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have ran it and it shows `test fails, there is recepition!!`. Can you please shortly explain the logic? Can I do this thing using Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test? @m170897017

Comment: @ShantanuBanerjee I repeat creating all the four random objects for 10000 times. Then make all these 40000 objects a list. Then use set() to remove duplicated objects in the list and count it length. If length is less than 40000, it means there is recepition. If length equals 40000, it means there is no recepition in the list.